# How to unlock NLog.config on Visual Studio 2019

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, nlog, nlog.config

After installing NLog and NLog.config using NuGet package manager
I am unable to edit NLog.config, it shows lock icon on it.
How to unlock it?

[image: lock icon on NLog.config file]

[image: my solution explorer]

Answer (score 5):

For newer projects the NLog.Config package is not
recommended.

From: https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.config

> Note: Unfortunately this package won't work well when using
> `<PackageReference>`
>
> Advised to:
>
> - download manually: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/NLog/NLog/dev/src/NuGet/NLog.Config/content/NLog.config
> - set "Copy To Output Directory" to "Copy if newer"

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem - the NuGet package for Nlog config was installed in a different location than the root project directory, like for example `C:\Users\User\.nuget\packages\nlog.config\4.7.7\contentFiles\any\any\NLog.config` instead of  `I:\workspaceVS\net50\ConsoleCoreApp1`.

I managed to solved the problem by copying manually the file Nlog.config into the project's root directory and then reference it in my .csproj file in the following way :

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  ...
  <ItemGroup>    
    <None Update="NLog.config">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="NLog.xsd">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    ...
  <ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

instead of :

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  ...
  <ItemGroup>    
    <None Update="C:\Users\User\.nuget\packages\nlog.config\4.7.7\contentFiles\any\any\NLog.config">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="C:\Users\User\.nuget\packages\nlog.schema\4.7.7\contentFiles\any\any\NLog.xsd">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    ...
  <ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

And now, when I release it, it shows directly in the output directory :

```
.(I:\workspaceVS\net50\ConsoleCoreApp1\bin\Release\net5.0\win-x86)
├── ...                   
└── Nlog.config           # Holds the configuration for Nlog
```

Comment: It worked great, only thing I also had to manually copy NLog.xsd also into the root of the project. Thanks for your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the `NLog.config` file in `{Project Folder}\bin\Debug\net5.0\`. You can open and edit it as you like with Notepad or Visual Studio.

Comment: This comment does not answer the actual question. The NLog.config file is locked for editing. How to unlock?